# Why alert isn't showing when pressing spacebar?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

Why we do not see the alert (the result of the alert function in Chrome) when you press the space bar, as opposed to pressing other keys, which gave us the alert.

```
<input type=text onKeyPress="my_keypress($event);">

function my_keypress($event) {
   var x = ($event.keyCode || $event.which);
   var x_char = String.fromCharCode(x);
   alert(
       'x: '+x + '\n' + 
       'x_char: ' + x_char + '\n' +
       'altKey: ' + $event.altKey + ' ' +
       'ctrlKey: ' + $event.ctrlKey + ' ' +
       'shiftKey: ' + $event.shiftKey
   );
}
```

Comment: pop up window !== alert....

Comment: The code as posted gives me "Uncaught ReferenceError: $event is not defined" in Chrome, for both space and other keys.

Comment: `my_keypress($event);`  <--- wrong

Answer (score 2):

Your `onKeyPress` code should be `my_keypress(event);` (notice the `$` sign removed).

When you press space and fire the alert, the alert appear but is closed immediately after when the space is released. If you want to see your alert, you have to keep the space pressed.

If you want to debug the `onKeyPress` event, I suggest you use `console.log` instead of an alert. `console.log` will write the output into the console log.